# Mysql Error 1136

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1136

I have read up on the error. It says that the sql passes more/less values than specified by table. But my table has 7 columns and i am sending 7 parameters, but still get the error. Please help

Books_out_on_loan

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `books_out_on_loan`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `books_out_on_loan` (
  `book_borrow_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `member_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `employee_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `isbn` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `date_issued` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_due` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_returned` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`book_borrow_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `book_borrow_id_UNIQUE` (`book_borrow_id`),
  KEY `member_id_idx` (`member_id`),
  KEY `employee_id_idx` (`employee_id`),
  KEY `isbn_idx` (`isbn`),
  CONSTRAINT `employee_id` FOREIGN KEY (`employee_id`) REFERENCES `employees` (`employee_number`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `isbn-book-loan` FOREIGN KEY (`isbn`) REFERENCES `books` (`ISBN`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `member_id` FOREIGN KEY (`member_id`) REFERENCES `members` (`member_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

SQL FILE:

```
INSERT INTO books_out_on_loan (book_borrow_id,member_id,employee_id,isbn,date_issued,date_due,date_returned)VALUES ('1','1','1','863758832-8','20160529','20160606',NULL);
INSERT INTO books_out_on_loan (book_borrow_id,member_id,employee_id,isbn,date_issued,date_due,date_returned)VALUES ('2','2','2','278860648-6','20160521','20160606',NULL);
INSERT INTO books_out_on_loan (book_borrow_id,member_id,employee_id,isbn,date_issued,date_due,date_returned)VALUES ('3','3','3','012454099-6','20160520','20160606',NULL);
INSERT INTO books_out_on_loan (book_borrow_id,member_id,employee_id,isbn,date_issued,date_due,date_returned)VALUES ('4','4','4','553185783-7','20160510','20160606',NULL);
INSERT INTO books_out_on_loan (book_borrow_id,member_id,employee_id,isbn,date_issued,date_due,date_returned)VALUES ('5','5','5','711473445-X','2016059','20160606',NULL);
INSERT INTO books_out_on_loan (book_borrow_id,member_id,employee_id,isbn,date_issued,date_due,date_returned)VALUES ('6','1','6','830664326-7','2016058','20160606',NULL);
INSERT INTO books_out_on_loan (book_borrow_id,member_id,employee_id,isbn,date_issued,date_due,date_returned)VALUES ('7','2','7','555264867-6','20160510','20160606',NULL);
INSERT INTO books_out_on_loan (book_borrow_id,member_id,employee_id,isbn,date_issued,date_due,date_returned)VALUES ('8','3','8','607119764-3','20160512','20160606',NULL);
INSERT INTO books_out_on_loan (book_borrow_id,member_id,employee_id,isbn,date_issued,date_due,date_returned)VALUES ('9','4','9','893613484-1','20160514','20160606',NULL);
INSERT INTO books_out_on_loan (book_borrow_id,member_id,employee_id,isbn,date_issued,date_due,date_returned)VALUES ('10','5','10','826004987-2','20160515','20160606',NULL);
```

SQL fiddle here, with working inserts :
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cbcc1

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's the ISBN that's the problem here; what happens if you remove the `-`?

Comment: Removed the hyphen. No Luck

Answer (score 2):

If you have any triggers like AFTER INSERT on the destination table and if there is a problem with this trigger, you will have this 1136 error which belongs actually to this trigger action. It is an old topic but checking these will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put N before every varchar value and execute the query, like this: N'863758832-8' (this is one of your ISBN's). This N means converting your string to Unicode and I think this will help.

And [Refer to this link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/155859/why-do-we-need-to-put-n-before-strings-in-microsoft-sql-server) There is an explanation of this. If this doesn't work you will also try to increase ISBN column from 13 to 20 maybe. Because hyphen will be taken as more than one character this mainly happens for UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: No luck on putting N before varchar. Also increased field size but no luck

Comment: @RenierSwart there is no problem with your data. You have a problem with your constraints. I created the same table on my MySQL and executed your inserts without a problem. For sure I did it without foreign keys because I don't have your full DB :)

Answer (score 0):

You have data truncates on these inserts, that might be causing an issue, I have corrected them here,

```
INSERT INTO books_out_on_loan (book_borrow_id,member_id,employee_id,isbn,date_issued,date_due,date_returned)VALUES ('5','5','5','711473445-X','20160509','20160606',NULL);
INSERT INTO books_out_on_loan (book_borrow_id,member_id,employee_id,isbn,date_issued,date_due,date_returned)VALUES ('6','1','6','830664326-7','20160508','20160606',NULL);
```